# Cannot Choose File type in Matrix file selection

Tags: matrix

I am creating a channel field using matrix and when I make a cell for files, I cannot choose file type. the selection is empty. The reason I ask is because when i use the cell to upload an image the image displays distorted.

Comment: This question isn't clear as posted. Please provide additional details... posting screenshots of settings will help.

Comment: What Anna said - also, the version of Matrix and EE would help. :)  Also, you might use the EE Server Wizard to make sure you have GD2 at minimum running on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Distortion of the image in your template is most likely is not coming from your Matrix field settings. Check your template code to make sure you don't have hard coded width or height. Also, look at CSS to make sure height or width isn't set there.

Comment: Sorry for the unclear post. There is no predefined height or width, If I edit the image, once uploaded, in my file manager it becomes distorted and in trying to solve the issue I realized I could not select file type in my matrix fields. My matrix settings are just a code to verify my purchase of the addon.

Comment: Post a screenshot in your question so we can see what the distortion looks like and where exactly it's happening.